# Regex match variable white space count at the beginning of the string

Tags: regex, unix

I want the following:

- match all white spaces (count >= 2), **BUT** if there are any (count >= 0) at the line start match them too.

The cases are (white space is underscored):

```
___x____xxx___x__x__xxxxx_xxxx_xx (1)
__xx____xxx___x__x__xxxxx_xxxx_xx (2)
_xxx____xxx___x__x__xxxxx_xxxx_xx (3)
xxxx____xxx___x__x__xxxxx_xxxx_xx (4)
```

Ant the matched white spaces should be as following:

```
___x____xxx___x__x__xxxxx_xxxx_xx (1)
___ ____   ___ __ __              (regex match)

__xx____xxx___x__x__xxxxx_xxxx_xx (2)
__  ____   ___ __ __              (regex match)

_xxx____xxx___x__x__xxxxx_xxxx_xx (3)
_   ____   ___ __ __              (regex match)

xxxx____xxx___x__x__xxxxx_xxxx_xx (4)
    ____   ___ __ __              (regex match)
```

I am going to use this regex to read log file using bash `awk` command, so if there is something unix specific regex it is ok.

I tried:

```
^[ ]{1,}[A-Z0-9]+[ ]{2,} --> not match
^[ ]{1,}[ ]{2,} --> not match
(^[ ]{1,})[ ]{2,} --> not match
```

Comment: You can use `awk -F ' {2,}' ...` to split fields on 2+ spaces but what are you going to do with there matched spaces?

Comment: @anubhava I wanted than revert this expression to get all strings without whitespaces

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this `awk` to split input fields on 2+ white spaces and print each field:

```
awk -F '[[:blank:]]{2,}' '{
for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) if ($i != "") print $i; print "========================"}' file
```

I have added a separator line for showing a record break.

**Output:**

```
x
xxx
x
x
xxxxx xxxx xx
========================
xx
xxx
x
x
xxxxx xxxx xx
========================
 xxx
xxx
x
x
xxxxx xxxx xx
========================
xxxx
xxx
x
x
xxxxx xxxx xx
========================
```

Comment: Thx for the answer, do I get `_xxx` or  `xxx`? I mean the beginning of the third string

Comment: Since 3rd line has only single space before `xxx` at start therefore it will print `_xxx` in output.